# In Unity script: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I decode game to unity project using Utinyripper to port it for pc, but i have one compilation error in unity. I know c# really bad, so if you can help, help me please.

error:
`Assets\Scripts\Assembly-CSharp\SFS\World\RocketJoints.cs(10,10): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'EOLNMPHKEPL' of 'JointGroup<C16662813002317105340415111315320>.JointGroup(C16662813002317105340415111315320)'`

CS CODE:

```
using System;
using SFS.Parts;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SFS.World
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RocketJoints : JointGroup<C16662813002317105340415111315320>
    {
        public RocketJoints(List<Joint<C16662813002317105340415111315320>> EBMACMECOCG, List<C16662813002317105340415111315320> CCCFILHCPJM, C16662813002317105340415111315320 EOLNMPHKEPL, C53132756575457052232432451725310 MNDKLFFKMFC)
        {
        }

        public C53132756575457052232432451725310 rocket;
    }
}
```

Comment: In general this doesn't sound quite legal though .. if the authors of that game would want you to do so they had given you access to the source code ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `JointGroup` doesn't allow a parameter less constructor!

Currently you are implementing a constructor with parameters for `RocketJoints` but it isn't calling any constructor in the base class so it assumes there would be a parameter less (or no) constructor in the base class.

However, it seems like the `JointGroup` class **has** a constructor that expects at least one parameter of type `C16662813002317105340415111315320` (the generic type parameter).

You child class constructor needs to inherit from the base class constructor and pass on according parameters like e.g.

```
public RocketJoints(List<Joint<C16662813002317105340415111315320>> EBMACMECOCG, List<C16662813002317105340415111315320> CCCFILHCPJM, C16662813002317105340415111315320 EOLNMPHKEPL, C53132756575457052232432451725310 MNDKLFFKMFC) : base(EOLNMPHKEPL)
{ 
    ...
}
```

---

In general: What's up with those type names?! You should use some more readable/meaningful names for your types!

Comment: I get this code from crypted files with renamed types, classes and other